# How to extract rules from conditional statements using NLP?

Tags: json, parsing, nlp

Consider that I am given an English sentence such as:

"If x1 is greater than x2, set y to 2"

Is there a method to extract the conditions and actions from such a statement in a "action"-parse tree or code format such as below?

```
if x1 > x2:
    y = 2
```

Comment: Do you have a NL processor handy ?

Comment: Any open source nlp library or python library would be good. Or even pre-trained models